# Configure LogLevel in Intellji Junit Run configuration in gradle project?

Tags: logging, intellij-idea, junit, gradle

Does anyone know how to configure loglevel when intellij runs a junit test from gradle?  It seems to jump to debug for all and I don't see any place to configure it.  The debug output is way too verbose for me.

Thanks

Peter

Comment: This question contains the solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9356543/logging-while-testing-through-gradle

Answer (score 6):

Logging for tests must be configured properly or we go to default unconfigured which is LOG EVERYTHING.  At least, that's my theory.

- Create test/resources/logback.xml
- Populate it with basic form
- adjust for your use case

Below we just force all logging to info.  Ideally, I want org.apache.* @ info and my classes at debug but I'll that requires me learning logback.xml format (which comes next)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d %5p | %t | %-55logger{55} | %m %n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
<root>
    <level value="INFO"/>
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
</root>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set up the path to log4j in VM option

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/C:/myfolder/log4j.properties
```

With this the logger will be available to all the test classes.
I have not tested with Gradle but have set up in maven and in my test configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the logging framework(s) used by the code under test, e.g. by placing a configuration file into `src/test/resources`. How exactly this is done depends on which logging framework is used.

PS: Unless this is about Android Studio, Gradle is not involved when running a unit test from IntelliJ.

Comment: Thanks Peter.  Is there documentation on which frameworks gradle uses by default?

Comment: Isn't this about logging performed by the code under test (or its dependencies), rather than logging performed by Gradle? As I said, Gradle is typically not involved when running unit tests from IntelliJ. Or are you testing a Gradle plugin?

Comment: Ok, so the problem is with intellij and how it runs unit tests not gradle then.  My commandline gradle execution is fine.  My IDE exeuction is way to verbose leading to a 2s test taking 2m.  So, I need to find a way to configure logging in intellij's execution of the junit unit test

Comment: First step is to figure out why logging is more verbose in IntelliJ. Normally this isn't the case. Perhaps the IntelliJ project isn't set up correctly (e.g. `src/test/resources` isn't marked as a resource folder, or, in earlier IntelliJ versions that don't have a concept of resource folder, `src/test/resorces` isn't marked as a source folder or the logging configuration file doesn't match IntelliJ's pattern for resource files). Or the Gradle build configures logging in some other way (e.g. sets a system property for tests) which isn't replicated in the IntelliJ setup.

Comment: Actually, first step is to figure out how logging gets configured in the Gradle build. It's common to have a config file in `src/test/resources`.

Comment: Thanks.  that was it... I started with this and configured logging properly  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25104992/configuring-logging-for-unit-tests-in-spring-boot-project-using-gradle-build